# Working locally, can't connect in Laravel to remote DB

Tags: pdo, laravel, laravel-3

I'm trying to work locally in Laravel and am having trouble connecting to a remote database.  I've used my domain name (domain.org) as my host, and then password, username and database name as normal.  But I get this error:

```
PDO::__construct(): Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:553)
```

If I look at the file where the error is happening, it's in my PDO connection in the MySQL driver.  I asked my ISP about settings and he said to use domain.org or the IP.  I tried both and I still get the error.  I tried setting the port to the standard 3306 and still get the error.  I can't use localhost as my host because that would refer to my local computer.  Can someone help?  What do I need to do to connect?

Comment: Download [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) PHP 5.2.2. After it installed I started Wamp, left clicked on Wamp in my icon tray, selected PHP->Version...and clicked on 5.2.2

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a difference between the encryption used in the version of MySQL on your web host, and that used by your PHP version.

Have a look at the accepted answer on this question:

[Remote mySQL connection throws "cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication" error from XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481620/remote-mysql-connection-throws-cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-the-old-insec)

As regards a solution, your web host may or may not be willing to change your MySQL settings - but my guess is that if they are running an old MySQL, they will also be running an old version of PHP. Laravel requires 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

To use "Remote Mysql" you would need to add your IP to the white-list on the server and also configure Mysql to accept remote connections

Answer (score 0):

Old question but, a lot people may need this, so adding what worked for me

In 5.6+, also will be working on lessor version

```
DB_CONNECTION_REMOTE=mysql
DB_HOST_REMOTE=remotehost
DB_PORT_REMOTE=3306
DB_DATABASE_REMOTE=database_name
DB_USERNAME_REMOTE=database_user
DB_PASSWORD_REMOTE=database_password
```

and in config/database.php

```
 'connections' => [
  'mysqlRemote' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_REMOTE', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_REMOTE', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_REMOTE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_REMOTE', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_REMOTE', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

and then in your controller

```
$records = DB::connection('mysqlRemote')->select( DB::raw('SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `table`') );
```

if your IP is white-listed, it should work fine, tested in Laravel 5.6