# Why doesn't CodeIgniter's mysql database driver work for remote databases in WAMP?

Tags: codeigniter, database-connection, wamp, lamp

I have not found any other question/answer that is this specific.

A few clarifications:

1. The same codebase for the project connects just fine on a `LAMP`, `MAMP` or even `XAMPP` stacks.
2. WAMP version is 2.2, Apache: 2.2.22, PHP, 5.3.13, MySQL: both 5.1.41 and 5.5.24 (but pretty sure these are only in use when trying to connect locally).
3. I don't have access to the MySQL server, so I cannot change any host settings
4. On Win7 ultimate (not sure what else you would need for environment specs)

I am fairly certain this issue has something to do with `WAMP`, not `CodeIgniter`, since the codebase works elsewhere.

Comment: are you sure you are able to connect to remote database ? (are you allowed to connect to sql server remotely?)

Comment: I'm digging deeper on this myself, and I've found that it seems to be linked the 'old password' issue that a lot of people are talking about. The problem is, that this problem ONLY happens through WAMP. Even my IDE (codelobster) is able to connect to the database using the credentials it found in the CI database config file! <--- it does this automatically.

Comment: I assume no errors given, right?

Comment: Right, the errors are being suppressed with '@' on mysql_connect. Let me try to get those errors for you. Also, it is CI version 2.1.3. in case you wanted to know. EDIT: There are three errors, 1)  OK packet 1 bytes shorter than expected, 2) mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. -- I know the server is using MySQL v5+, but it still gives those errors  ... 3)  Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:553)

Comment: I found this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481620/remote-mysql-connection-throws-cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-the-old-insec), user had same errors as you do. There is nice answer how to solve this.